# Harbor freight jump pack, broken input jack, repairable?

Tags: jump-start, battery-charger

I received a harbor freight Cen-tech battery jump pack as a gift. It got knocked over when I took it camping to charge my phone and inflate my bed. Now the input jack (the part with the prongs) is loose and won't attach to the charging cord easily and doest seem to be charging when it is. Is it fixable? Lots of videos on how to swap out the battery inside but nothing on fixing that part. I was assuming on how easily it broke there would be more about it.

Comment: Source a replacement and fit it - usually means splitting the case.

Comment: Hi forrest, could you post the picture of it? because in many cases the charging prongs can be fix easily, unless it is broken apart / the plastic is damaged.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering how this is on topic for the site?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 We've accepted tool use questions; I think tool repair is close enough.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica so re-grinding screwdrivers and heat treatment as well?

Comment: @SolarMike I agree it's not a bright line boundary. Perhaps you or Paulster2 should vote to close; the community might find your view more persuasive than mine.

Comment: Just ask an electronics technician to install a new jack for you.